# What is the Java 17 alternative for com.googlecode.robotframework-maven-plugin : robotframework-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, robotframework

We have been using the following plugin:

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.robotframework-maven-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prepare-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <testCasesDirectory>src/test/resources/robotframework/prepare</testCasesDirectory>
                                <tests>
                                    <test>Prepare.Prepare-Tests.Prepare NREG</test>
                                </tests>
                                <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                                <variables>
                                    <variable>TAGS:${tags}</variable>
                                    <variable>NOTAGS:${notags}</variable>
                                </variables>
                                <variableFiles>
                                    <variableFile>test-data/common.py</variableFile>
                                    <variableFile>test-data/servers/${arc}.py</variableFile>
                                </variableFiles>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execute-test</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <testCasesDirectory>test-data/nreg/tests</testCasesDirectory>
                                <outputDirectory>test-data/nreg</outputDirectory>
                                <argumentFile>test-data/nreg/tests/tags.txt</argumentFile>
                                <nonCriticalTags>
                                    <nonCriticalTag>TDD</nonCriticalTag>
                                </nonCriticalTags>
                                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

We want the test project to be migrated to Java 17.
I tried using

```
<groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.0</version>
```

But, it throws an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.robotframework:robotframework-maven-plugin:2.1.0:run (execute-test) on project tarc-robot: Invalid test data or command line options.
```

Some of the posts on internet suggests, the testCasesDirectory can only contain robot files and not HTML files.We have a lot of HTML files generated at the testCasesDirectory location.

Could someone suggests an alternative for com.googlecode.robotframework-maven-plugin: robotframework-maven-plugin which supports HTML files in testCasesDirectory or a way to make this plugin work with Java 17 ?
com.googlecode.robotframework-maven-plugin: robotframework-maven-plugin needs tools jar version 1.6, which is no longer present in Java 17 but was present in Java 8.